# AIX 6.1: WARNING: Duplicate symbol:

Tags: c, aix

I am busy porting an application written in C from Solaris SPARC 10 to AIX 6.1.

I am getting huge amounts of "`WARNING: Duplicate symbol:`" errors. I have tried using `#ifndef` to only include header files if needed, but still getting the same duplicates.

Any ideas what would cause this? I have seen similar posts but nothing concrete yet.

As an example I am getting:

```
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: onCheckCallbackFunc
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: onCommitCallbackFunc
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: onConfirmCallbackFunc
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: onRollbackCallbackFunc
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: onMessageArrivedCallbackFunc
```

And if I run the following command on that lib:

nm -X64 ./libtest.so

I get the following( just a snippet)

```
onCheck:F-1          -         692
onCheckCallbackFunc  B   536877592           8
onCheckCallbackFunc  d   536877064           8
onCheckCallbackFunc:G820 -           0
onCommit             D   536876400
onCommit             d   536876400          24
onCommit             d   536877024           8
onCommit:F-1         -         824
onCommitCallbackFunc B   536877600           8
onCommitCallbackFunc d   536877072           8
onCommitCallbackFunc:G820 -           0
onConfirm            D   536876424
onConfirm            d   536876424          24
onConfirm            d   536877032           8
onConfirm:F-1        -         956
onConfirmCallbackFunc B   536877608           8
onConfirmCallbackFunc d   536877080           8
onConfirmCallbackFunc:G820 -           0
```

Why are symbols being duplicated above?

Thanks again

Lynton

Comment: You ought to show us the code.

Comment: Well, it's just a log, not code. Now you should grep the source for (say) `onCheckCallbackFunc` and see, where it's defined and where it's declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linker tries to link object files containing objects with the same name.

Assuming you did not explcitly declared different objects using the same name, this happens most probably by compiling the same source to different object files which then in turn are all passed over to the linker.

A common case for this to happen is to let the compiler #include some sources more then once.

Another possible scenario is that you create two libraries out of the same sources and try to link them both to your main object.

Or you include sources into a library *and* into the main build.

In any such cases the linker wil choke.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the suggestions, much appreciated.....I'm just curious, if worst case the WARNINGS stayed it should not influence the running application surely? Am I correct?